# Conditional state integer number

Tags: webforms

Using Drupal 8 and the new webform module "8.x-5.0-beta19".

Like it a lot! Many options now to control the webforms.

Problem:
I have one input field 'NUMBER'.
When the web visitor enters a number greater than 0... the other input field should appear.
So on the second input field, I do a conditional statement.

Make visible when Value is not ---> 0

Seems to be this options only accepts integers greater than 0, but not 0.
See image... When saving the 0 disappear and 2 he accepts and does save it....
[image]

Is this a bug... does somebody has a solution?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. I am guessing that the 0 is being interpreted as an empty string.  Please create an issue in the webform issue queue (https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?version=8.x)

Comment: Here is the ticket. https://www.drupal.org/node/2916409

Answer (score 1):

This is issue has been fixed. @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2916409